# PowerShell and AD show different user expiration date

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2012

After running:

```
Set-ADUser username -AccountExpirationDate "05/18/2017 7:00:00 PM"
Get-ADUser username -Properties AccountExpirationDate
```

I get this in PowerShell: AccountExpirationDate: 5/18/2017 7:00:00 PM

But user properties shows that the account expires on 5/17/2017.

What causes this?

[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCA4d.png)

[AD Property Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7MfE.png)

Comment: what is the functional level of the DC your ADUC is pointed to?

Comment: @Colyn1337 Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a test user, and use the MMC GUI to set an account expiraton. Then use Get-adUser to look at the value that is set.When you make GUI choice of 5/19/2017 the Get-Aduser returns 5/20/2017 12:00:00 AM

Notice how the GUI says "End Of" and does not give you a time choice, only date. The "End of" day X here is 0 hundred hours of the next day.
Also, date/time properties in AD are always UTC times, and GUI tends to adjust for local time zone offset.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx

You can calculate the equivalent GUI choice in powershell with

```
((get-date "5/19/2017").addDays(1)).toUniversalTime()
```

Comment: Glad to help. As your account looks fairly new, I'll just mention how accepting answers works on the stackExchange family of sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work